# Mapping of Eloquent models to tables?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

We are able to create Eloquent models for tables. But how Laravel knows to which table to associate a model with? Do we have something similar to `hbm.xml`(mapping file we use for Hibernate) which says this model means this table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table name is a protected property:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'my_users';
 }
```

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)

Comment: i assumed you are talking about Laravel 4, is this ok?

Comment: That property is for when the name of the table is different from the name of the model. If you name the model as the table, you do not need that property

Answer (score 3):

You can manually override the table name as the above answer states.
Its just a protected member of the Model.php class.

```
  class User extends Eloquent {
      protected $table = 'my_users';
  }
```

Otherwise, a lowercase, plural format is automatically used, based on the classname of the Model. (class_basename($this))

As shown here... (Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php)

```
 /**
 * Get the table associated with the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTable()
{
    if (isset($this->table)) {
        return $this->table;
    }

    return str_replace('\\', '',    Str::snake(Str::plural(class_basename($this))));
}
```